Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to runtime: Error: await connected: disconnected
While executing a cell in Google Colab, my aim was to display a selection of random rows from a DataFrame containing columns labeled Id, condensed_summary, and generated_image. Initially, I attempted to exhibit the entire dataset comprising 200 rows, only to encounter display issues. Subsequently, I opted to showcase a subset of n_results random rows, but to my dismay, the display failed, prompting a session restart.
In my endeavor to troubleshoot, I experimented with various values for n_results. When I substituted n_results with 10, Google Colab presented a pop-up message in the following manner:

This is the code I'm utilizing, which yields the error:
def show_results(df_result, images_dir_path: str, n_results: int):
  from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
  from PIL import Image
  from io import BytesIO
  import base64
  from os import listdir
  import random

  image_file_paths = []
  img_strs = []

  if n_results >= len(df_result):                           # all samples
    image_file_paths = listdir(images_dir_path)
  else:                                                     # random sampling
    df_result = df_result.sample(n=n_results).reset_index()
    image_file_paths = random.sample(listdir(images_dir_path), n_results)

  for idx, f in enumerate(image_file_paths):
    img = Image.open(images_dir_path + f)
    img_buffer = BytesIO()
    img.save(img_buffer, format="PNG")
    img_strs.append(base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode())
    df_result.at[idx, 'generated_image'] = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{'+str(idx)+':s}" width="300" height="300">'
  html_all = df_result.to_html(escape=False, index=False).format(*img_strs)
  display(HTML(html_all))

df_result = pd.DataFrame({"id": ids, "condensed_summary": condensed_summaries})
show_results(df_result, IMAGES_DIR_PATH, 10)

My code operates smoothly for small values of n_results, such as 10, but encounters crashes when handling larger numbers, failing to display any output. This dilemma prompts me to seek solutions for both displaying all results and deciphering the message's implications.

I had the same issue with different code. For me it worked to "Disconnect and delete runtime"
